# Can we make ASP.NET Core REST API support both JSON & SOAP?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, web-services, wcf

I want to make a REST API that supports both json & soap. I tried the `SoapCore` nuget package, but I get errors like:

> IEndpointRoutebuilder does not contain a definition for 'UseSoapEndpoint and the best extension method overload SoapEndpointExtensions.UseSoapEndpoint <1EmployeeBiz> (IApplicationBuilder, string, SoapEncoderOptions, SoapSerializer, bool, ISoapModelBounder, WediFileOptions, bool, bool) requires a receiver of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationbuilder",

> The request reached the end of the pipeline without executing the endpoint: SoapCore. Please register the EndpointHiddleware using IApplicationBuilder.UseEndpoints (...) if using routing. "

I used this code in `startup.cs` file:

```
endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<IEmployeeBiz>("/Service.asmx", new SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
```

Can you guide any other alternatives to make a REST API support json & soap?

UPDATE:

We migrated .Net Core to .Net 6 and we have multiple legacy customers who sends soap requests to our API's. We don't want to ask customers do changes at their end, so we want our RestAPI support both JSON & XML requests & responses.

Comment: First, which .NET version are you using? The errors suggest there's a version mixup. Second, SOAP services don't use an `.asmx` extension, or any file extension. ASMX was an obsolete framework replaced by WCF in 2006 and never supported the SOAP specifications and standards that came out since.

Comment: REST and SOAP are complete opposite web methods. Essentially one is stateless and the other state full with XML. I think you need to tell us the **why** behind this idea...

Comment: @JeremyThompson SOAP isn't stateful. State isn't the difference between REST and HTTP or SOAP APIs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think that perception is because SOAP goes hand-in-hand with RPC semantics, and plenty of RPC-based systems are stateful (_...looking at you, DCOM_)

Comment: @Dai SOAP isn't RPC, it's was mainly *document* based. All Microsoft talks at Teched conferences in 2000-2010 were about *documents*. And even my COM+ (not DCOM) services were always stateless. *BUUUUT* not only is it infinitely easier to create tooling for RPC, the *document-first* services used by eg airlines and designed by large consultancies like IBM were horrendous to call. The document designers just didn't keep implementation in mind.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos More _messages_ (as in _message-passing_) than "_documents_", though, right?

Answer (score 0):

Supporting both JSON and SOAP in a single API might add some complexity. Consider the specific requirements of your application and whether supporting both formats is necessary. If you can, it's often simpler to have separate endpoints or even separate services for JSON and SOAP.

In your Startup.cs file, configure services for both JSON and SOAP.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddSoapCore();
```

Configure your API endpoints to handle both JSON and SOAP requests.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<YourService>("/YourSoapService.asmx", new BasicHttpBinding());
});
```

Create your API controllers to handle JSON requests. ASP.NET Core supports JSON by default, so you can use the ApiController attribute and return JSON responses.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // Your JSON logic here
        return Ok(new { message = "JSON response" });
    }
}
```